# Как Открыть файл, занятый другим процессом, как стрим для чтения

Tags: c#, .net

Есть файл логов, в который сторонний процесс в реальном времени пишет данные. Требуется открыть файл как поток на чтение, при этом не потревожив другой процесс, который в него пишет, у него не должны пропасть права на файл. 
Наивная попытка в лоб говорит, что файл занят другим процессом.

Comment: Так закройте поток и откройте снова, а при записи, убивать открытый и снова открывать на запись.

Comment: я пишущим процессом не управляю, сторонняя программа.

Comment: Просто нужно правильно оформлять вопрос, а то не понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как обычно, ломаешь голову пару часов, решаешь спросить и находишь ответ сам за пару минут, у меня так половина вопросов заканчивается).

```
     FileInfo log = new FileInfo(@"log.txt");
     using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(log.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Вообщем нужно было обратить внимание на третий параметр в FileInfo.Open

Comment: Отмечу, что работоспособность этого кода зависит от дружелюбности другого процесса — тот может открыть файл в режиме запрета чтения другими.